# How do gColab have an access to a gDrive directory (not a file)

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I would like to have an access to a gDrive directory from gColab notebook.

I already found a solution to read a file but not a directory. Indeed, for my application (transfert learning with PascalVOC07 images database), I have a code which need to browse a directory stored in my gDrive.
This directory has a lot of files, sub-directories, ... and my code is made to calculate with only the address (directory) of the complete database.

```
# Installation de PyDrive
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
auth.authenticate_user()

#Autoriation de connexion
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

# drive : accès à gDrive
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Création du lien vers le module PascalVOCDataGenerator qui est        stocké sur gDrive
personal_module = drive.CreateFile({'id': '18OiN-      HEzI8lfEWTYIViWXwybu18S2ibx'})

# Chargement du module sur gColab
personal_module.GetContentFile('data_gen.py')

from data_gen import PascalVOCDataGenerator

# id gDrive du répertoire des données PascalVOC07
data_dir = drive.CreateFile({'id': '10Lfr0nFtZB15H3PboABgTngb_kJ0dBjY'})

# Chargement du module sur gColab
data_dir.GetContentFile('/')

data_generator_train = PascalVOCDataGenerator('trainval', data_dir)
```

So, with this code, it's possible to upload my specific module "PascalVOCDataGenerator" from gDrive to gColab and import it.
One of its parameters is the directory of the databasa : data_dir.

But error "No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata" !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use PyDrive. A simpler approach is to mount your entire Drive as a FUSE filesystem using this snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

This is also available via the file browser in the left-hand pane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, with this method it's possible to have an access in gDrive. To be able to charge a library, I found a solution : after make a link with gDrive (your solution), I have to make this : !cp '/my_path/data_gen.py' '/content/'. After no problen to make : import data_gen in my Python code.